# Hide child of li and show by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu in responsive side. This menu has a sub-menu like:

```
.navbar ul li ul
```

I want if the parent menu has a child menu like my code I want to hide it and when I need to show it, click the parent menu to show it.

I tried this code but it does not work.

```
$(".navbar ul li").each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(this).children('ul').attr('class')){
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('span').remove();
    }
});

$(".navbar ul li span").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('ss');
    $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active-mobile');
    $(this).parent('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: paste your html markup

Comment: I strongly recommend you to set an id to the ul you want to show/hide, add the style display:none, and create an onClick function to set Display to true

Comment: You remove the span and then want to toggle a class on it? Also you check if the ul has a class, but not the name of it?

Comment: if you use `.remove()` your element won't be available to show afterwards as you have removed it from the dom. But, really please include your html.

Comment: @RohanKumar Why so complicated? http://jsfiddle.net/nYQdH/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks overly complicated. Try the simple approach.

Hide all submenus in the beginning with CSS:

```
#nav li > ul {
    display:none;
}
```

Then toggle a class indicating the shown element (and perhaps use some animation):

```
$('ul#nav > li').click(function () {

    $(".show").removeClass("show").find("ul").slideUp();
    $(this).addClass("show").find("ul").slideDown();    
});
```

This is the most basic working dropdown menu, one could of course extend it with a lot of additional stuff. E.g. the example fiddle has an additional check if the clicked element was already shown and toggles it if it is the case. But this basic code should give you a sufficient starting point.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nYQdH/4/)